# Connecting to multiple DB Instances from Code

Tags: c#, .net

I was creating a console app that will execute a script in a DB and get some path location of several files and this tool will verify whether the file exist in that location or not.

currently I have a requirement that in the server the user has 2 sql instances.(eg., ABCD/test1, ABCD/test2)
So is it possible to connect to multiple instance from C# code and execute the script in each instance in a single run.
If possible how can I use the connection string?

Comment: yes you can connect to as many different SQL servers and databases as you like. Either add more connection strings to your app.config, or hard-code them separately. Depending which data access library you're using, there will be different ways to create new connections. You really need to ask something more specific. It's unclear precisely where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be doing low-level database access, this seems fine to me. Of course, if you only need one database connection open at any time, you could abstract most of the code into a method (that takes an SQL command/text as a parameter and returns the result), but this may not be the case in your situation.

You could also make things slightly neater by making use [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) of statements, as such:

```
using(var sqlConnectionA = new ...)
using(var sqlConnectionB = new ...)
{
    try
    {
        // Perform queries here.
    }
    catch (SqlException exSql)
    {
        // SQL error
    }
}
```